# How can I make the automatic timed logout longer?

Tags: kubernetes-dashboard

The web session timeout for Kubernetes Dashboard is pretty short. I can't see any setting or configuration parameter to change it.

I tried inspecting the container contents with `kubectl exec`, but there does not seem to be any shell (sh, bash, ash, etc.), so I can't see what web server parameters are configured inside.

I would like to make this timeout longer, to make it easier to keep track of job executions for long periods of time.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 33):

There are two ways. When you deploy the manifest originally, this can be done by modifying the Container Args to include this directive: `--token-ttl=43200` where 43200 is the number of seconds you want to set the automatic timeout to be.

If you want to manipulate the configuration post-deployment, then you can edit the existing deployment which will trigger the pod to be redeployed with the new arguments. To do this run `kubectl edit deployment -n kube-system kubernetes-dashboard` and add the argument mentioned above to the `args` section.

EDIT: If you are using V2 of the Dashboard (Still in beta) then you will need to change the namespace in the command from `kube-system` to `kubernetes-dashboard`. (Or somewhere else if you customized it)

EDIT2: You can also set `token-ttl` to 0 to disable timeouts entirely.

Comment: Checked on Kubernetes 1.16.3. `kubectl edge` doesn't exist. In command from @TJ  replace `edge` with `edit`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Edge has never been a command. Thanks for correcting. :)

Comment: Delete `kube-system` from your `kubectl edit` ...I don't think its needed. So the real command is `kubectl edit deployment -n kubernetes-dashboard`. You can precise also that this line need to be added: `- --token-ttl=x` just after this one: `- --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard`. So you need to search for the last one in the yaml file. Replace x whith the timeout time that you want to set (0 to disable complitely the timeout).

Comment: Did you see this in the post you responded to? `EDIT: If you are using V2 of the Dashboard (Still in beta) then you will need to change the namespace in the command from kube-system to kubernetes-dashboard. (Or somewhere else if you customized it) `

Comment: I've added the additional `--token-ttl=0` but it's not clear to me what timeout is being increased by the change? following the guide https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md when I generated a new token using `kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard create token admin-user` I obtain the same short lived token.

Comment: Setting the `--token-ttl` argument instructs the Dashboard to expire an authenticated session after `#` seconds. `0` in this case disables expiration. `600` would be 10 minutes. The token itself remains valid across time.

Comment: Running `kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard create token admin-user` it's getting a token with a TTL of about 1h and dasbhoard expires, despite the change in the deployment yaml; I can easy verify the token content at https://jwt.io; it contains the `exp": 1662976724,  "iat": 1662973124, etc`
I think the actual question is `how can one get a token with no expiration date`? (like in the older versions where exp was omitted!)

Comment: Sounds like something has changed. I suggest you open a new question since this question was in reference to extending/disabling the automatic logout after a token is accepted. Not preventing a token from being permanently invalidated after a period of time.

Comment: @DanM I saw this comment on Reddit today and thought of you: https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/ydsuwh/kubernetes_dashboard_what_i_am_missing/itu913a/

Comment: @TJZimmerman thanks yep that's a good idea. In the meanwhile I used the K8s certificate and generate my own token where I can freely edit the `exp`; 
The cert I used to modify and sign the token is the `/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key` `/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub` pair.

Answer (score 16):

In the v2.2.0 version (~year 2021) of the default installation (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.2.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml), they use `kubernetes-dashboard` as the namespace.

The command would look like this:

```sh
kubectl edit deployment kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard
```

The change would look like this:

```yaml
# ... content before...

    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --auto-generate-certificates
        - --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard
        - --token-ttl=0 # <-- add this with your timeout
      image: kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.0

# ... content after ...
```

As TJ Zimmerman suggested: 0 = no-timeout.

Comment: use `kubectl edit deployment kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system` command instead of `kubectl edit deployment kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard` in microk8s

Answer (score 7):

If using [helm](https://helm.sh/), the token-timeout can be set in the `values.yaml` like this:

```yaml
extraArgs:
  - --token-ttl=86400
```

Answer (score 3):

The same as previous answers, but if editing files isn't your bag and you prefer to just run a command, you can patch your (default) dashboard deployment with:

```
kubectl patch --namespace kubernetes-dashboard deployment \
  kubernetes-dashboard --type='json' --patch \
 '[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/args/2", "value": "--token-ttl=43200" }]'
```

(adjust 43200 to whatever TTL value you want to set).

Comment: Can no longer login after running this command. Dashboard interface says:
Unknown error (0): Http failure response for api/v1/csrftoken/login: 0 Unknown Error

Comment: The answer assumes the default installation as documented here: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#install. Try reinstalling the latest version of the dashboard.

Comment: That's the installation method I used. After 30 minutes I was able to login again without any changes. Maybe you have to wait for the old session to expire?

Comment: verified now, works (of course, because it matches the [3] index of the args in current official dashboard manifest). it's good for automation in case no option to manually edit after the kubectl apply. thanks. one concern though: does the patching delete text at [3] if the default yaml will change and will have >=3 args already? can you do "append" in it, no matter how many items in list already exit? lol, just did a test and verified it adds new item in between existing ones in list, so it's safe to use!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the same effect for a `microk8s` `dashboard` addon is by editing the file `/var/snap/microk8s/common/addons/core/addons/dashboard/dashboard.yaml` to include the --token-ttl=604800 argument within the rest of the container arguments:

```
      containers:
        - name: kubernetes-dashboard
          image: kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.7.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          args:
            - --auto-generate-certificates
            - --namespace=kube-system
            - --token-ttl=604800
```

After making this change, you can disable and enable the addon to apply the modification:

```
microk8s disable dashboard ; sleep 10; microk8s enable dashboard
```

Admittedly, this approach might seem a bit unorthodox and potentially unsustainable if the addon version gets updated. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a simpler method to make this change persistently within microk8s. Ideally, one would hope for a more flexible configuration option, similar to those found at `/var/snap/microk8s/current/args/`, but it seems that `microk8s` doesn't currently expose customization settings for the dashboard in that location.